# What auth flow to use with spa and service account msal

Tags: oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm, azure-ad-msal

There's so many different flows in the Microsoft docs that I have no clue what one is needed for me. I am using React and Python. (I understand node, so if someone explains using node/express its fine)

What user should see:
A page with a button to login, nav is there but wont work till logged in. The login creates a popup to sign in with Microsoft account. Once signed in, the user will be able to use nav to see dynamics information.

What I am trying to do:
This app needs to sign in a user and obtain the users email through 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'.(no client secrets needed) Then I need to send that email in this request;

(The tenant == {company}.crm.dynamics.com.)

```py
 allInfo = requests.get(
            f'https://{TENANT}api/data/v9.0/company_partneruserses?$filter=company_email eq \'{email}\'', headers=headers).json()
```

This backend request needs to have a client secret to obtain the information. So I believe my backend also needs to be logged on to a service account. I believe I need to get a token for my backend to make requests on behalf of the service account.

What I have:
I have a React frontend that is signing a user in and calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me' correctly and getting that email. Once I get the email, I am sending it to my backend.

Now I have no clue how to proceed and have tried many things.

What I have tried for backend:
Attempt 1: I get a token but error: {'error': {'code': '0x80072560', 'message': 'The user is not a member of the organization.'}}. Problem is, this id is the Azure AD ID. It should def work

```py
@app.route('/dynToken', methods=['POST'])
def get_dyn_token():
    req = request.get_json()
    partnerEmail = req['partnerEmail']
    token = req['accessToken']
    body = {
        "client_id": microsoft_client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "scope": SCOPE_DYN,
    }
    TENANTID = '{hash here}'
    res = requests.post(
        f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANTID}/oauth2/v2.0/token', data=body).json()

    dyn_token = res['access_token']

    headers = {
        "Prefer": "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"",
        "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=full",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {dyn_token}"
    }
    try:
        allInfo = requests.get(
            f'https://{TENANT}api/data/v9.0/company_partneruserses?$filter=company_email eq \'{email}\'', headers=headers).json()
        print(allInfo)
```

Attempt 2:
Same code but instead of  f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANTID}/oauth2/v2.0/token' its
f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'. Error: An exception occurred: [Errno Expecting value] : 0. Because it returns an empty string.

Now I don't know if I am even on the right path or where to go. I know the routes work themselves if the token is correct. I used only SSR with no react and these routes work. But I need the React to be there too. I just don't know what flow to use here to get what I need. The docs make it easy for /me route to work. But the {company}crm.dynamics.com docs don't really provide what I am trying to do.

Additional info after comment:

What 'f'https://{TENANT}api/data/v9.0/company_partneruserses?$filter=company_email eq '{email}'', headers=headers"  is trying to get are API keys. Full code :

```py
 try:
        allInfo = requests.get(
            f'https://{TENANT}api/data/v9.0/company_partneruserses?$filter=company_email eq \'{email}\'', headers=headers).json()

        partner_value = allInfo['value'][0]['_company_partner_value']

        response = requests.get(
            f'https://{TENANT}api/data/v9.0/company_partnerses({partner_value})', headers=headers).json()

        return {'key': response['company_apikey'], 'secret': response['company_apisecret']}
```

Then once it has the keys:

```py
def api_authentication(apikey, apisecret):
    headers = get_headers() #<-- same headers as above with using dyn_token 
    response = requests.get(
        f'https://{TENANT}api/data/v9.0/company_partnerses?$filter=company_apikey eq \'{apikey}\' and company_apisecret eq \'{apisecret}\'&$select=company_apikey,company_apisecret,_company_account_value,_company_primarycontact_value,blahblah_unassignedhours,company_reporturl', headers=headers).json()
    return response
```

Afterwards I am able to get all the information I am looking for to send back to my frontend for the client to see. (By making multiple request to crm with these keys)

Comment: Are you required to make a call to crm.dynamics.com on user's behalf or is this a call on behalf of your python backend? Are they validating the token against the same tenant in Azure AD?

Comment: Currently this is a call on behalf of my python backend. At the moment, they are not  validating the token against the same tenant as I dont know what flow is actually needed. 

It seemed to me that I only needed the clients email to make the crm request. So currently that is all my frontend is doing. The backend needs to make the crm requests. Once the email is received, the call is trying to obtain api keys to then do a api-auth. I will go back and add the additional code above so its more clear

Comment: Then why do you need a token to call CRM? Do they use it to make other calls inside Azure?

Comment: Its to find the clients api keys that are stored in the crm. Then every call afterwards use these keys. The token to call CRM is not the client but the service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client_credentials grant that you are using should work, provided the CRM trusts the token issued to the client (your python backend). Please use MSAL library instead of hand crafting the token request. It will save you time and eliminate errors.

Comment: My frontend is using the MSAL library for graph/me request. Backend is only getting token with https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token. There is no /authorize route for backend currently because I was getting the access token for my backend from this route. Does the backend also need to use MSAL library?

Comment: The token endpoint is not accepting JSON, so it is easier to use MSAL for python to avoid issues with form encoding.

Comment: The endpoint accepts json when something is returned. The error was due to an empty string being returned. The reason I thought MSAL for backend wouldnt work is due to it needing a redirect uri for auth. Wouldnt this clash with the frontend redirect/ make for a double login?

Comment: You are using client credentials flow which is strictly server to server. No redirect is taking place. It is a simple post to the token endpoint with client credentials and scope in the payload. However, the payload is not json even though the token is returned in a json.

Comment: You do not have to use MSAL on the backend. You can construct you payload as key=value&key=value&… by hand.

Comment: After talking to you, I have a theory. I was transferred to this project and was told that it currently uses a service account. But after what you said, I believe the current code is just using this "service account" as a user with more permissions. With the code they had, it had no client_credentials grant, only refresh tokens. Since that code was only SSR, I believe they actually logged in twice but didn't notice because they had the same redirect_url. 

I added this client_credentials grant to try to get CSR to work due to being told it was a 'service account'

Comment: So I believe, if the service account is set up properly, it will work. Seems to have never been set up properly because they unintentionally got the end result they wanted. I really appreciate your input on this, I haven't dealt with service accounts so I couldn't tell what exactly was going on. Thanks!!